# Regex substitution doesn't work if group contains newline flag

Tags: python, regex

If my pattern group doesn't contain newline (`\n`) character, everything works fine:

```
contents = b'''
xdlg::xdlg(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)
    : customized_dlg((UINT)0, pParent, pApp)
'''
pattern = rb'(\w+)(::)(\1)'
res = re.search(pattern, contents, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if None != res:
    print(res.groups()) # output is: (b'xdlg', b'::', b'xdlg')
sub = rb"\1--\2--\1"
contents = re.sub(pattern, sub, contents, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
print(contents) # output is b'\nxdlg--::--xdlg...(to save space, unchanged string is ignored)
```

but if I change `pattern` to contain `'\n'`, `re.sub` fails to change `contents`:

```
pattern = rb'(\w+)(::)(\1)(.*\n*:\n*.*)(\(UINT\)0)'
res = re.search(pattern, contents, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
if None != res:
    print(res.groups()) # output is (b'xdlg', b'::', b'xdlg', b'(x_app* pApp, CWnd* pParent)\n\t: customized_dlg(', b'(UINT)0')
sub = rb"\1--\2--\1"
contents = re.sub(pattern, sub, contents, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
print(contents) # the output doesn't change anything!
```

what am I doing wrong here?

---

(I'm using Python 3.4.2)

Comment: Why are you using `.*\n*:\n*\.*`? With the `re.DOTALL` flag you could simply write `.*:.*` or even better `[^:]*:[^(]*` (which would probably be more efficient).

Comment: `(.*\n*:\n*.*)` This doesn't match `\n    : `. You're missing out the space/tabs before the `:`

Comment: @dhke, in fact, '.*' can't miss anything with 're.DOTALL'

Comment: Instead of calling the `re` functions you could `re.compile` the pattern and then use `pattern.sub`. This would have avoided the problem since it wouldn't have been possible to confuse the flags with the count since the flags are provided to `compile` and the count to `sub`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend passing the regex flags as a named argument when using the `re` module.
[Here's the sub() method signature from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
```

In your code, your "flags" will be interpreted as count instead, because the re module flags are in fact integers and `re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE == 16`.

Your code should be this:  (`re.MULTILINE` has no effect for this particular regex pattern)

```
contents = re.sub(pattern, sub, contents, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

If you don't used named arguments, you need to pass in `count` as well. `0` means that all instances will be replaced.

```
contents = re.sub(pattern, sub, contents, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: no, it is not the key, i have checked it with only re.DOTALL, the result is the same with mine.

Comment: Please read my answer again. `re.DOTALL` doesn't matter. The method arguments is what you did wrong. `flags` is actually an integer, so it will be interpreted as `count` if you pass it as the 4th argument.

Comment: I believe you should also mention that the regex he's using is quite inefficient and more complex than it ought to be...